# Where to check if a cron job was ever run?

Tags: 13.10, cron

I set a few cron jobs locally on my machine. They were supposed to run each night at 8 PM.

Where can I see or check that they actually run?

Answer (score 3):

On a default installation the cron jobs get logged to

```
/var/log/syslog
```

so you can check it there.

To see just cron jobs in that logfile by running

```
 grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

EDIT:

Check this [link](http://bencane.com/2011/11/02/did-my-cronjob-run/) to learn more how to read log file of cron and how to determine which job has ran or no

Comment: I get a result `Jan 16 09:17:01 CRON[19498]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)`. Does this maybe list cron jobs for today only?

Comment: If I do `crontab -u userName -l`, I get output of my personal cron jobs where each ends like `JOB_ID_1, JOB_ID_2`. So the IDs 1 and 2 should appear in the listing, like `CRON[ID]` in the listing above?

Comment: @ubuntico check edit